# C++11: reinterpreting array of structs as array of struct's member

Tags: c++, c++11, reinterpret-cast

Consider the following type:

```
struct S
{
    char v;
};
```

Given an array of `const S`, is it possible to, *in a standard conformant way*, reinterpret it as an array of `const char` whose elements correspond to the value of the member `v` for each of the original array's elements, and vice-versa? For example:

```
const S a1[] = { {'a'}, {'4'}, {'2'}, {'\0'} };
const char* a2 = reinterpret_cast< const char* >(a1);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a1[i].v == a2[i]) << ' ';
```

Is the code above portable and would it print `true true true true`? If not, is there any other way of achieving this?

Obviously, it is possible to create a new array and initialize it with the member `v` of each element of the original array, but the whole idea is to avoid creating a new array.

Comment: The question comes down to whether a `struct` containing a `char` is required to have no special alignment.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: If it has alignment > 1, then it must have padding, because if it's size 1 then in an array the second item would be unaligned. So padding is the real question. The alignment doesn't matter after the question of padding has been resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Formally the `struct` may have padding so that its size is greater than 1.

I.e., formally you can't `reinterpret_cast` and have fully portable code, except for ¹an array of only one item.

But for the in-practice, some years ago someone asked if there was now any compiler that by default would give `sizeof(T) > 1` for `struct T{ char x; };`. I have yet to see any example. So in practice one can just `static_assert` that the size is 1, and not worry at all that this `static_assert` will fail on some system.

I.e.,

```
S const a1[] = { {'a'}, {'4'}, {'2'}, {'\0'} };
static_assert( sizeof( S ) == 1, "!" );

char const* const a2 = reinterpret_cast<char const*>( a1 );

for( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
    assert( a1[i].v == a2[i] );
}
```

---

Since it's *possible* to interpret the C++14 and later standards in a way where the indexing has Undefined Behavior, based on a peculiar interpretation of "array" as referring to some original array, one might instead write this code in a more awkward and verbose but guaranteed valid way:

```
// I do not recommend this, but it's one way to avoid problems with some compiler that's
// based on an unreasonable, impractical interpretation of the C++14 standard.
#include <assert.h>
#include <new>

auto main() -> int
{
    struct S
    {
        char v;
    };

    int const compiler_specific_overhead    = 0;    // Redefine per compiler.
    // With value 0 for the overhead the internal workings here, what happens
    // in the machine code, is the same as /without/ this verbose work-around
    // for one impractical interpretation of the standard.
    int const n = 4;
    static_assert( sizeof( S ) == 1, "!" );
    char storage[n + compiler_specific_overhead]; 
    S* const a1 = ::new( storage ) S[n];
    assert( (void*)a1 == storage + compiler_specific_overhead );

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i ) { a1[i].v = "a42"[i]; }    //  Whatever

    // Here a2 points to items of the original `char` array, hence no indexing
    // UB even with impractical interpretation of the C++14 standard.
    // Note that the indexing-UB-free code from this point, is exactly the same
    // source code as the first code example that some claim has indexing UB.
    char const* const a2 = reinterpret_cast<char const*>( a1 );

    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
    {
        assert( a1[i].v == a2[i] );
    }
}
```

---

<sup>*Notes:*

¹ The standard guarantees that there's no padding at the start of the `struct`.</sup>

Comment: I think the implied pointer arithmetic in `a2[i]` induces undefined behavior.

Comment: @T.C. I don't know about the indexing, but as mentioned there is *already* formal UB. One can't make it more UB, just like one can't be just a little pregnant. :) However, in practice the only worry about that is that a certain compiler conceivably could use it to sabotage-“optimize” the code…

Comment: "not portable" does not imply UB. @T.C. is right that the UB comes from the pointer arithmetic not the use of `reinterpret_cast`, see [expr.add] p6.

Comment: This seems like a recipe to produce code that subtly fails due to optimizations based on aliasing assumptions. So a `static_assert` is not sufficient. You have to verify that the compiler, every compiler, and every change of options or versions, doesn't break the code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You're right, but your statement misleads because (1) compilers ability to compile ordinary code is verified by testing the code with the compilers that one uses, which is done anyway, i.e. there's nothing extra to do, and (2) if a compiler, say g++, fails to compile this reasonably, then that's a good reason to ditch that compiler. Compilers are our tools, not our masters. Use tools that give productivity, ditch the ones that make the job harder.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf The break does not happen today. It happens 7 years from now when the code starts skipping the read of `[0]` but not at `[1]`, but only when the code is auto-lifted to run on the GPU (which depends on hardware and the runtime environment).  The problem is, again, not today, but your commitment to testing and auditing every compiler upgrade and compiler change this code ever experiences.  If you are writing throw-away code, UB away.  If not, you are writing a blank debt cheque for the future maintainer of your code to repay.

Comment: @Yakk: OK, I'll add a formally correct version of the code that does exactly the same internally. That means that the UB concerns for this case are nonsense.

Comment: Formally, the placement new reuses the storage occupied by the `char` array, ending its lifetime (see [basic.life]/1). Your second loop then accesses elements of an array whose lifetime has ended, which is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @T.C: For example, given `::new (storage+1) S{42};`  the second byte of the array `storage` is used, and in your view, as I understand it, this second byte now has ceased to exist as an object, and instead an `S` object now lives there. Where the point is that it's now allegedly UB to index that particular location. That is absurd. But if that's *not* what you mean, then, to see that the bytes are not the array, consider making `storage` 100 bytes larger than the 4 bytes used for the `S` array. Then ... it's UB to index the first 4 bytes, that have ceased to exist? Again, that's absurd.

Comment: As far as I can tell, under the formal object model the entire array object's lifetime ends because part of its storage is reused, and subsequently indexing any part of it is UB because pointer arithmetic is only defined inside an array (treating non-array objects as array of 1 for this purpose) and you don't have one anymore. The current model does leave a lot to be desired - [C++03 and later `std::vector` is unimplementable in it](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/msg/std-discussion/p4BXNhTHY7U/ahp5CzNFQQAJ).

Comment: @T.C. The view that *using* a byte or sequence of bytes in a much larger array of bytes, makes that array cease to exist as an object, is absurd. An array of bytes doesn't cease to exist in any sense by doing something to a few bytes in there, even if that something is to use those bytes as storage for something. Plainly speaking, it's a forced absurd interpretation of the standard, and it proves, by *reductio ad absurdum*, that the position that leads to this absurdity, is wrong.

Comment: I don't really disagree as an intuitive manner; indeed, the current working draft provides [special dispensation for arrays of `unsigned char`](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#3), so that creating objects within them doesn't end the array's lifetime. Arrays of `char` (or indeed of any other type), on the other hand, get no such special casing.

Comment: @T.C. That's awful. A special case kludge for C++17. I had no idea that it had got that far, I'm sorry. Suffice it to say, with C++14 I lost faith in the committee's ability to create quality work. But this... I had no idea. :(

Answer (score 8):

Trivially, no - the `struct` may have padding. And that flat out breaks any reinterpretation as an array.

Comment: What if the padding is explicitly removed therefrom?

Comment: @набиячлэвэли : That would require a compiler-specific extension; then no general rule applies.

Comment: @набиячлэвэли You'd still be breaking aliasing rules. Lots of real code that broke aliasing rules and worked fine for many years started breaking when compilers got smarter optimizations. It's a terrible idea to assume that it will work.

Answer (score 4):

The pointer arithmetic in `a2[i]` is undefined, see C++14 5.7 [expr.add] p7:

> For addition or subtraction, if the expressions `P` or `Q` have type "pointer to *cv* `T`", where `T` and the array element type are not similar (4.5), the behavior is undefined. [ Note: In particular, a pointer to a base class cannot be used for pointer arithmetic when the array contains objects of a derived class type. — end note ]

Because of this rule, even if there is no padding and the sizes match, type-based alias analysis allows the compiler to assume that `a1[i]` and `a2[i]` do not overlap (because the pointer arithmetic is only valid if `a2` really is an array of `char` not just something with the same size and alignment, and if it's really an array of `char` it must be a separate object from an array of `S`).

Comment: This quote is out of context, and it's apparently nowhere in C++11.

Comment: I found it in C++14. It's can be interpreted in at least two ways, one reasonable with a purpose, and (yours) one unreasonable sans purpose. Worth noting that C++14 is the first version of the standard that incorporates bits of very low quality: this unclear wording is one example.

Comment: The wording comes from [DR 1504](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1504) which has DR status so addresses a defect in C++11

Comment: Re "type-based alias analysis allows the compiler to assume that a1[i] and a2[i] do not overlap", no, that's only so with your unresonable interpretation of "array" as original array, instead of the array at hand. However, this interpretation can (possibly) have been adopted in a perverse compiler.

Comment: What is the "array at hand"? Where is that defined in the standard? If the wording I quoted _isn't_ saying that you can't treat an array of A as an array of a different type B, what is it saying? Under your fanciful interpretation why would a pointer to base not give you an "array of base at hand" and so why would the wording have been added by DR 1504?

Comment: In the code in the question the array at hand is pointed to by `a2`. Hopefully you agree that the C++14 standardese you quoted applies to arrays accessed by pointers. Generally, such a paragraph in the standard does not apply to an "original array" or anything outside the immediate closest context. You'd get a huge problem with e.g. placement `new` that way. Oops, Jonathan says you cannot use the reuslt... :)

Comment: why would a pointer to base not give you an "array of base at hand" and so why would the wording have been added by DR 1504? Under what circumstances where you have a "pointer to _cv_ `T`" would `T` _not_ be the same as the array element type, if the "array at hand" is whatever type the pointer happens to be? If your interpretation is correct then the entire paragraph is nonsensical. The alternative is that your interpretation is nonsense, and the paragraph says what it was intended to say (although I think it's too strict, see the ""related question in issue 2182).

Comment: How does placement new relate to [expr.add] and pointer arithmetic of the form `P[Q]`? What are you claiming I've said about placement new?

Comment: Oh. Consider, for the example at hand, that the `a1`, instead of directly being a raw array, is a pointer obtained from placement `new` on a suitably aligned array of `char`. Then your original array is an array of `char` items. :) If the rules are at all consistent. Then with your interpretation indexing `a1` would be UB. But indexing `a2`, with the same item type as the original array, would be fine. :-D

Comment: A placement new-expression begins the lifetime of an object. A `reinterpret_cast` doesn't.

Comment: Now you've lost me. It doesn't make sense even as pure misdirection.

Comment: Wait. Are you claiming that (1) a `reinterpret_cast` here can produce a different pointer value than placement `new`, or alternatively, are you claiming that (2) there is UB if the compiler *knows* that the pointer was produced by casting, so that one has to hide the pointer production from it?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Placement `new` creates an object.  `reinterpret_cast` does not.  Are you under the impression that the naive local assembly code you imagine is generated by a C++ statement is the meaning of the C++ code?  That is not true.  Take [`const int x = 3; int* p = (int*)&x; *p=7; std::cout << &x << ':' << x <<'\n' << p << ':' << *p << '\n';`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66620e4171048a28)  This prints that the data at the same address has the values `3` and `7`.  Why?  UB.  The compiler saw an actual `const int`, deduced it did not have to read it to print `x`, and insanity

Comment: @Yakk: Your example is about `const` correctness. That's not relevant: it's techno-babble. And when you descibe how your telepathic brain has found that I naively imagine machine code or the meaning of C++ code, well, you're into non-intelligent argumentation (notwithstanding that Alan Turing wrote that he took telepathy seriously).

Comment: @cgeer it is about undefined behaviour. Yes, I used casting away const as an example of undefined behaviour. Someone imagining the naive machine code produced locally by each line would see that the place where the UB happened eas when I wrote to `x` through `*p`. They could say "`x` could be written to ROM, that write may trap, and it it did not trap `x` has its value changed": thus the printout should show the same value for `x` and `*p`. It does not, because the compiler assumes nothing casts away const. The same can happen with any UB.

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd be inclined to use a compile-time transformation if the source data is constant:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct S
{
    char v;
};

namespace detail {
    template<std::size_t...Is>
    constexpr auto to_cstring(const S* p, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return std::array<char, sizeof...(Is)> {
            p[Is].v...
        };
    }
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto to_cstring(const S (&arr)[N])
{
    return detail::to_cstring(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main()
{
    const /*expr if you wish*/ S a1[] = { {'a'}, {'4'}, {'2'}, {'\0'} };

    const /*expr if you wish*/ auto a2 = to_cstring(a1);


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a1[i].v == a2[i]) << ' ';
}
```

output:

```
true true true true
```

even when the data is not a constexpr, gcc and clang are pretty good at constant folding complex sequences like this.

Comment: Hm, copying. What about arrays of some million items or more?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf as ever, it depends... How many times are we doing it? Can the compiler elide the copy? Is it a candidate for constant folding? And so on. In a tight loop, with mutable data, probably not. But in many cases, even though a copy is written, after an optimisation pass, it won't actually happen. Compilers today are pretty good.